# Is there a new "best practices" technique for demonstrating stall recovery?

Tags: flight-training, usa, stall, cfi

This is a question that is probably best suited for active flight instructors. I was doing an FBO checkout and the CFI asked me to demonstrate power on and power off stall recoveries, but well before the stall he asked me to recover. His explanation is that it is the new best practices for teaching and demonstrating stalls to recover "before" the aircraft actually stalls. In essence, the recovery demonstrations consisted of setting up the plane for landing and take-off config, and slowing it down till the stall warning came on, then almost immediately "recovering." It seems too easy. However, his reasoning made sense, but I have never heard it before:

1. It prevents new pilots from getting comfortable flying with the stall warning buzzing.
2. It teaches pilots to avoid the stall in the first place. (Prevention)
3. Its safer.

While his points are all factually correct, I think this defeats the purpose of knowing how to recover from a stall.

Any current CFIs out there that can explain if this is a new "best practice" for demonstrating stall recovery?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29755/62), although it seems there may be [some more recent guidance](https://www.flyingmag.com/faa-redefines-slow-flight-and-stall-procedures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its related to this [safety alert for operators](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/june/13/faa-explains-revisions-to-slow-flight-stall-tasks) that was issued back in may. You can find the [full text from the FAA here](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2017/SAFO17009.pdf) but the pertinent chunk for the private pilot is...

> (1) Private Pilot – Airplane ACS, Power-Off & Power-On Stalls. With
>   the exception of performing a thoroughly briefed full stall maneuver,
>   a pilot should always perform the **stall recovery procedure when a
>   stall warning occurs**

Comment: Going into a fully developed power-on stall in my short-time in flight school was one of the highlights! I distinctly remember the feeling of hanging in the harness pointed basically straight at the ground (a few thousand feet up of course). Or maybe I remember it with rose colored glasses...

Comment: So the kid was right. Great answer Dave!

Comment: @Devil07 looks to be that way, although my flight school/FBO (just did my 90 day rental checkout) is still doing full break stall training and testing. Frankly I think its important that student pilots see the full break but thats just me, the FAA clearly has their reasons and their data.